# Keyboard Shortcuts for numeric keypad keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, shortcuts

I want to remap the numeric keypad keys so that I can use them for Keyboard Shortcuts. Here's the issue: When I press `7` in Keyboard Shortcuts, it appears as "Home (keypad)." This isn't very helpful because the keys on my keyboard aren't labeled with these mappings. Furthermore, if I press keypad `+`, Keyboard Shortcuts registers it as just `+`--no differentiation on keypad key versus shift-=.

So I have a two-part question:
1. How can I change the labels displayed in Keyboard Shortcuts?
2. How can I change the internal mapping of keypad `+` to distinguish it from shift-=?

I'm on version 18.04.